# Remove repeating tuples from a list, depending on the values in the tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple contains 2 elements:

- The 1st element is a tuple with some numbers, e.g. (1, 4, 2). This
  is in fact a path, the numbers in which are IDs of nodes.
- The 2nd element is a number, which is a score of the path.

For example, the list may be

```
pathList = [
    ((1, 2),    4),
    ((1, 4, 2), 2),
    ((1, 2),    6),
    ((1, 2),    3),
    ((1, 4, 2), 3)
]
```

Now I want to remove tuples which have the same paths (1st element) as others, while keeping the one that has the highest score (2nd element) among them.

For example, after the process, `pathList` should be

```
pathList = [
    ((1, 2),    6),
    ((1, 4, 2), 3)
]
```

The order is not important.

Is there an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary ([*dict.setdefault*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method)to preserve your paths as key and relative scores as a set (O(1) complexity for adding values) of values then select the max score for each unique path :

```
>>> pathList = [
...     ((1, 2),    4),
...     ((1, 4, 2), 2),
...     ((1, 2),    6),
...     ((1, 2),    3),
...     ((1, 4, 2), 3)
... ]
>>> 
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in pathList:
...   d.setdefault(i,set()).add(j)
... 
>>> [(i,max(j)) for i,j in d.items()]
[((1, 2), 6), ((1, 4, 2), 3)]
```

Comment: *O(1) complexity for adding values* - Even your original version with list has O(1) complexity for adding values (as you used `append`)

Comment: @thefourtheye Indeed but calling the `list.append` takes a bit more time than `set.add()`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use pandas and groupby:

```
import pandas as pd

pathList = [
    ((1, 2),    4),
    ((1, 4, 2), 2),
    ((1, 2),    6),
    ((1, 2),    3),
    ((1, 4, 2), 3)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(pathList, columns=["elements", "occurences"])

max_only = []

for name, group in df.groupby("elements"):
    max_only.append([name, group.occurences.max()])

print max_only
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing about python is the script can always be simple,
i am just sorting the list here.

```
newPathList =[]
pathList = sorted(pathList, reverse =True)
oldx = 0
for i in pathList:
    x,y = i
    if x!= oldx:
        newPathList.append(i)
        oldx = x
print newPathList
```